# Unable to archive a project because: The project does not have a Package Name (but it does!)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Since 2-3 hours my project does not allow me anymore to export a signed APK because of that error.

I have set a package name (I'm working on this project since a week) and suddenly stopped working after I created a new emulator device, I've done nothing apart creating a new device.

*If I run the app in debug mode works as expected*

**[EDIT]**
I've found the issue, looks like the problem is related to the project path name being too long, seriously?!
I don't want to change my default folder where I save all my projects based on which type of tool I'm developing.

Anyway, I've tested it, I created a new solution in the root folder of my D: partition and inserted all the files from my original solution, tried to use 'Archive all' and worked
This error helped me to understand the problem:

```
Failed to generate Java type for class: Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView/IOnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor due to System.IO.PathTooLongException
```

**Now the question is: How I can keep my original folder?**

**[ORIGINAL]**
I've also created a new project but the problem persists... I'm out of idea about what could be


*This is the log generated when manually using MSBuild*

```
_ResolveAndroidSigningKey:
  Creating "obj\Release\100\android_debug_keystore.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
_Sign:
  D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\zipalign.exe -p 4 "D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\
  CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotification.Android\obj\Release\100\android\bin\com.mutu_adi_marian.cgs_jdsportsn
  otification.apk" "bin\Release\\com.mutu_adi_marian.cgs_jdsportsnotification-Signed.apk"
  C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\java.exe -jar D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.
  0.2\lib\apksigner.jar sign --ks "C:\Users\mutua\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass
  :android --ks-key-alias androiddebugkey --key-pass pass:android --min-sdk-version 25 --max-sdk-version 29  "D:\Softwa
  re Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotification.Android\bin\Release\co
  m.mutu_adi_marian.cgs_jdsportsnotification-Signed.apk"
  Signed android package 'bin\Release\com.mutu_adi_marian.cgs_jdsportsnotification-Signed.apk'
Done Building Project "D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotif
ication.Android\CGSJDSportsNotification.Android.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).

Project "D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotification.sln" (
1:2) is building "D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotificati
on\CGSJDSportsNotification.csproj" (3:11) on node 1 (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).
D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNoti
fication.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "SignAndroidPackage" does not exist in the project.
Done Building Project "D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotif
ication\CGSJDSportsNotification.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotif
ication.sln" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotification.sln" (SignAndr
oidPackage target) (1:2) ->
"D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNot
ification.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (3:11) ->
  D:\Software Development\Visual Studio\C#\Mobile\Android\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNotification\CGSJDSportsNo
tification.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "SignAndroidPackage" does not exist in the project.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:09.02
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.mutu_adi_marian.cgs_jdsportsnotification" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:label="CGSJDSportsNotification.Android" android:icon="@drawable/appIcon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the solution:

First of all be sure to have **EnableLongPaths** set to **1** into the
*registry* (I already had this to 1)

Open your **<project_name>.csproj** and **<project_name>.Android.csproj** file with Notepad++ or even Windows Notepad and firstly try only with this line

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Delete the **bin** and **obj** folder from *<project_name>.csproj* and *<project_name>.Android.csproj*, open the solution and try to use 'Archive all', if still does not work close the solution, reopen the files and add also this line

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <IntermediateOutputPath>SHORTEN_FOLDER: I still used my main prject folder but in the root I created a .in folder</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Delete the bin and obj folder from <project_name>.csproj and <project_name>.Android.csproj, open the solution and try to use 'Archive all'.
At this point Visual Studio still complained about the **Archive Path** being too long, so I just moved my Archive folder to a shorten path and this fixed the issue.
(To change the Archive path go to **Tools>Options>Xamarin>Archives location**)

I hope this will help you as well, maybe a second option that can solve this issue (because before creating a new device everything was working fine) is to reinstall Visual Studio (definitely not a valid option for me)

Comment: Can you please mark this answer so that we can help more people with same problem:)?